# setting bagging in R adabag

Tags: r, machine-learning

I cannot seem to get `adabag`'s `bagging` and `predict.bagging` to work.

In `predict.bagging` manual page, there is the following:

```
 library(adabag)
 library(rpart)
 data(iris)
 names(iris)<-c("LS","AS","LP","AP","Especies")
 sub <- c(sample(1:50, 25), sample(51:100, 25), sample(101:150, 25))
 iris.bagging <- bagging(Especies ~ ., data=iris[sub,], mfinal=10)
 iris.predbagging<- predict.bagging(iris.bagging, newdata=iris[-sub,])
 iris.predbagging
```

That is nice and working. However, when I change the `newdata` in `predict.bagging` a bit, it stops working.

Mainly, I cannot really delete or change the `Especies` column, which is weird, since that one is the one I am supposed to be predicting! An example.

```
testdata <- iris[-sub, ]
result <- predict.bagging(iris.bagging, newdata=testdata)
```

....this works fine and is almost carbon copy of the example. However, this produces an error

```
testdata <- iris[-sub, -5] #this deletes the Especies column!
result <- predict.bagging(iris.bagging, newdata=testdata)
```

but also this

```
testdata <- iris[-sub, ] 
testdata$Especies <- c("virginica") #sets up everything as virginica
result <- predict.bagging(iris.bagging, newdata=testdata)
```

produces an error!

What is going on? I want to make a classifier using `bagging`, but I can't know the results in advance, that defeats the point.

edit: Allright, it gets even weirded.

```
> testdata <- iris[150,]
> predict.bagging(iris.bagging, newdata=testdata) #all working
> testdata
     LS AS  LP  AP  Especies
150 5.9  3 5.1 1.8 virginica
> is(testdata)
[1] "data.frame" "list"       "oldClass"   "vector"    
> testdata$Especies = "virginica"
> testdata
     LS AS  LP  AP  Especies
150 5.9  3 5.1 1.8 virginica    #!!!the same thing!!!
> is(testdata)
[1] "data.frame" "list"       "oldClass"   "vector"    #the same object type!!!
> 
> predict.bagging(iris.bagging, newdata = testdata)
Error in matrix(unlist(value, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE), nrow = nr,  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
2: In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
3: In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
4: In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
5: In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
6: In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
7: In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
8: In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
9: In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
10: In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
>
```

Answer (score 3):

Oh, I got it, a little bit.

Apparently, in the last `Especies` column, there **has** to be a factor, not a vector of strings. So, in order to change it, I have to factorize it like this:

`testdata$Especies <- factor(c("virginica"), levels=c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"))`

If I have a data frame without the last column, I have to add it anyway and the levels of the factor must be exactly like the factor of the original table, the actual contents is irrelevant.

I am not accepting my answer as the best so far, because someone can be better in explaining why.

Comment: I still don't understand why this would be the case, but I'm glad that other people are having this issue too. Usually, `predict` functions only require new input data and not a response.

Comment: So creating the dummy response variable row and interpreting it as a `factor` did the trick?

Comment: I haven't touched R for nearly 2 years (fortunately!!), so I can't really say now :(